# android cannot resolve method setcontentview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I came across an error today in android studio. I am trying to create a about us screen in the app. The layout xml file has been created. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

error: cannot resolve method setcontentview(int)

```
package example.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class AboutFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about_screen);
}

}
```

Comment: Use onCreateView() in Fragmnets, setContentView(R.layout.about_screen); works in Activity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your class extends `Fragment` and you have `setContentView(R.layout.about_screen);`. `setContentView` is a method of Activity class.

Instead inflate `about_screen.xml` in `onCreateView` of `Fragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_screeen, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```